# Integral $ I=\int_{-r}^r \int_{-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}} \sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2 + y^2}{x^2 + y^2 - r^2}} dy dx $

Tags: integration

I have to solve [this integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28integrate+%28sqrt%281-%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2-r%5E2%29%29%29+dy+from+-sqrt%28r%5E2-x%5E2%29+to+sqrt%28r%5E2-x%5E2%29%29+dx+from+-r+to+r)

$$
I=\int_{-r}^r \int_{-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}} \sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2 + y^2}{x^2 + y^2 - r^2}} dy dx
$$
with substitution and then the trick that $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} = \dfrac{ d{\arcsin(x)}}{dx}$$

Can someone give me a suggestion on what I should substitute in order to continue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you have to let wolfram alpha calculate again, when the page is loaded or it says it doesn't understand the expression

Comment: I think that this question is more suitable for the math stack exchange site

Comment: ok sorry i'll ask it over there

Comment: Maybe you could do us all a favor and write the integral you want to evaluate explicitly in this page.  This would help those who might want to help you.

Comment: $$\int^r_{-r}dx\int^{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}_{-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2-r^2}}dy$$?

Answer (score 1):

let$x=\rho\cos{t},y=\rho\sin{t}$
then
$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{r}\rho\sqrt{1-\dfrac{\rho^2}{\rho^2-r^2}}d\rho d\theta$$
$$\Longrightarrow I=2\pi\int_{0}^{r}\rho\sqrt{\dfrac{r^2}{r^2-\rho^2}}d=2\pi r\int_{0}^{r}(r^2-\rho^2)^{-1/2}d\left(-\dfrac{1}{2}(r^2-\rho^2)\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following.

The value $I$ of the integral is $\int_D f(x,y) dS$, where $S$ is the area of the domain $D$. In our case $D$ is the disk of radius $r$ centered at the origin. In polar coordinates $x=t\cos\varphi$, $y=t\cos\varphi$ we have 
$$f(x,y)=g(t,\phi)=\sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2 + y^2}{x^2 + y^2 - r^2}}=\sqrt{1 - \frac{ t^2\cos^2\varphi + t^2\sin^2\varphi }{ t^2\cos^2\varphi + t^2\sin^2\varphi - r^2}}=\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-t^2}},$$

and

$$I=\int_D f(x,y) dS=\int_D g(t,\varphi) dS=\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{r} g(t,\varphi) tdtd\varphi=
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{r}\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-t^2}} tdtd\varphi=$$ $$2\pi r\int_0^{r}\frac{tdt }{\sqrt{r^2-t^2}} =
\pi r\int_0^{r}\frac{dt^2}{\sqrt{r^2-t^2}} =
\pi r\int_0^{r^2}\frac{du}{\sqrt{r^2-u}} =
\pi r\int_0^{r^2}\frac{d\left(\frac u{r^2}\right)}{\sqrt{1-\frac u{r^2}}} =
$$
$$\pi r\int_0^{1}\frac{dv}{\sqrt{1-v}}=\pi r(-2\sqrt{1-v})\Big|^1_0=2\pi r.$$